# Is is possible to see the input labels for a randomforest model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a random forest model built like this:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)


X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is there any method I can call (or attribute I can use) to see the column names used to make the  model?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean 'the feature' used at a particular node, you could try printing the [trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to retrieve column names from a trained Random forest classifier from my experience, there is also a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485285/retrieve-list-of-training-features-names-from-classifier) for an identical question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the Trees using

`clf.estimators_`

Then you can traverse the Tree using custom code.[Check [here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree)
 Then you can take it to whatever format you want *i.e. Array/DataFrame*

#### A sample code to view one of the Tree

```py
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data  
y = iris.target

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

model  = clf.estimators_[0]  # Checking the first Tree

from sklearn.tree import export_text
tree_rules = export_text(model, feature_names=iris.feature_names)
print(tree_rules)
```

[image]